# A javascript class that takes a JSON object and converts it into an attribute property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried to convert a `JSON` object into an attribute string in javascript.

Like:

```
json = {a:"1", b:"2"};
```

and the output will be html elements, like

```
"< div a='1', b='2'>< /div>"
```

I tried in this way,

```
var json = {a:"1",    b:{c:"2", d:"3"}};
function myFunction(obj, json) {
    for (var i in json) {
        obj[i] = json[i];
    }
}
```

As far i know the obj is created but I failed to make the proper output which can be used in the html, because the json object can be nested. Sorry again for this noob question.

Well, i write something like this:

```
var o = {a:"1",    b:{c:"2", d:"3"}}    
function objToString (obj) {
    var str = '<div ';
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str += p + '=' + '"'+obj[p]+'"' + ',';
        }
    }
    str= str.replace(/,$/ , '>');
    return str;
}
objToString (o);
```

But the above code not working for nested object. So, i tried this way:

```
var o = {
    a: "1",
    b: {
        c: "2",
        d: "3"
    }
}
console.log(o);
var tx = new String();
tx = '<div ' + JSON.stringify(o) + '>';
console.log(tx);
tx.replace(/:/gi, '=');
tx = tx.replace(/}/, '');
tx = tx.replace(/{/, '');
console.log(tx);
```

But this time the output not match for proper html... Haven save me :(

Comment: in the case of `{a:"1",    b:{c:"2", d:"3"}}` what should be the output

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JNHF6/1/

Comment: JSON is a text format for data interchange.  What you have is a "javascript object".

Comment: Dear @ArunPJohny, in this case output will be < div a='1', b='{c:2, d:3}'>. Actually i want to use the css(json object) in my html.

Comment: did you had a look at the fiddle.... it seems to be doing that... can you give the real use case so that we can look at any other possible solutions

Comment: there will be an object like {class:"image", style:{width:"2", height:"3"}} and i want to use this object in my html like <div class="image" style="width:2 ;height: 3"></div> using javascript. @ArunPJohny

Comment: do you want to create a new `div` with the given properties or add the properties to an already existing `div`

Comment: yes i want to create a new div.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JNHF6/3/

Comment: Please explain why downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I programmed something  that should deal with your problem. If I understood you right, this is exactly what you need.

I solved this problem using recursion and the visitor pattern. Works like a charm.
I didn't test it for all possible types but missing types can be inserted easily when needed.
Arrays do crash currently - you will need to catch this if they appear too.

Some explanation:

1) I tested the types of the values.

2) I initialized an array that store values I could find.

3) I wrote a recursive method that tests object-properties for being objects

4) If the property is a object it will be used recursively in the same method.

5) If the property is no object, it's data will be added to the previously initialized array.

6) After the recursive method's executing I debug the array and create a sample output.

```
// the object to use:   
var o = {a:1,    b:{c:"2", d:"3"}}  

// some type testing:
//alert(typeof(o.a)); // string
//alert(typeof(o.b)); // object


// implement a recursive method that reads all
// the needed stuff  into a better-to-handle array.
function readAttributesRecursive(obj, arr) {
    for(prop in obj) {

        // get the value of the current property.
        var propertyValue = obj[prop];
        // get the value's type
        var propertyValueType = typeof(propertyValue);


        // if it is no object, it is string, int or boolean.
        if(propertyValueType !== 'object') {
            arr.push({
                property : prop,
                value : propertyValue,
                type : propertyValueType // just for debugging purposes
            });
        } 
        // otherwise it is a object or array. (I didn't test arrays!)
        // these types are iterated too.
        else {
            // red the object and pass the array which shall 
            // be filled with values. 
            readAttributesRecursive(propertyValue, arr);
        }
    }
} // END readAttributesRecursive(obj, arr)



// ok, lets get the values:
var result = new Array();
readAttributesRecursive(o, result)

console.debug(result);

//  the result looks like this:
//  [
//      { property : "a", type : "number", value: "1" }
//      { property : "c", type : "string", value: "2" }
//      { property : "d", type : "string", value: "3" }
//  ]


// And now do the <div>-stuff:
var div = '<div';
for(i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    var data = result[i];
    div += ' ' + data.property + '="' + data.value + '"';
}
div += ">Some text</div>";

console.debug(div);
```

Note:
Please do never create HTML-elements like this (using strings)!
Use document.createElement() and work with created DOM-elements. Using strings can result in strange behaviour , bugs and less readable code ... (strings are not EXACTLY treated like DOM-elements after being inserted into DOM)

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for jQuery's `.attr()`? You can create an element, add a few attributes and text and append it to the body like this:

```
$('<div/>')
  .attr({
    "class":"some-class",
    "id":"some-id",
    "data-fancy": "fancy pants"
  })
  .text('Hello World')
  .appendTo('body');
```

Comment: your example helps me a lot! @bill